# HTML in url to on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have a link with HTML content in Rails 5 but it's seems that my code doesn't work:

```
<%= link_to "<i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
<span class="pull-right-container">
<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
</span>".html_safe, admin %>
```

I've got a SyntaxError in Admin::IndexController#index
I want to go to my admin/index controller with index action...

Thanks.

Comment: i think your route helper `(admin)` is wrong. Can you provide you `rake routes` output

Comment: it might help if you add the actual error trace to your question along with the index action for the controller ... providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @PardeepDhingra
https://codeshare.io/PsjLN

Comment: give this a try `<%=link_to raw("<i class='fa fa-dashboard'></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
<span class='pull-right-container'>
<i class='fa fa-angle-left pull-right'></i>
</span>"), admin %>`

Comment: @PardeepDhingra :( don't work
undefined local variable or method `admin' for #<#       <Class:0x000000040a2d60>:0x007f478df43f18>
Did you mean?  admin_url

Comment: Both should work `admin` and `admin_url`. As per the routes you have `admin` helper in last.

Comment: is this working ? `<%=link_to "test", admin %>`

Comment: @PardeepDhingra not working same things...

Answer (score 1):

If you can't make route helpers work, use explicit `url_for` syntax instead. You can also pass a block to put HTML in your links more easily:

```
<%= link_to url_for(:controller => 'admin/index', :action => :index) do %>
  <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
  <span class="pull-right-container">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

Running `rake routes` (or `rails routes`, for Rails 5) will show you what route helpers you have available, and help to identify the one you need. Be aware that the helper listed is the helper *prefix*, not the entire helper name - add `_path` to complete the method name. In your case, that means the helper is `admin_path`, not just `admin`.

Comment: This code may work but why `admin` helper is not working?

Comment: Because there *is* no `admin` helper. I don't know what the route helper is, but running `rake routes` will find it.

Comment: @ArtOfCode hmmm i try to put your code but is missed now
I have no error but the link don't show...

Comment: one error he forgot to put `=` copy now. in front of `link_to`

Comment: @ArtOfCode this link https://codeshare.io/PsjLN Thomas has share which has output of `rake routes` according to this last route helper is `admin`. It should work.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra Ah. That's not the helper method name; it's the helper method name *prefix*. I.e. you need to add `_path` to it to make it work.

Comment: Even he has tried `admin_url` which should also work